# How much time passes in WandaVision?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time, wandavision

Specifically, how long were the people of WestView

> being held captive in Wanda's hex?

I got the impression that is was weeks if not months but I'm not sure what the official word is.

Comment: It’s clearly enough time for twin boys to be conceived, born, and grow up to be pre-teens.

Comment: @MikeScott - They seemed to be aging very rapidly.

Comment: I'd also guess on the order of weeks but a related question would be how long before a neighbor showed up?

Comment: @MikeScott did you watch it? It's clearly not.

Comment: @OrangeDog It clearly is, because all of those things happened. The question is, how long did those things take.

Comment: @MikeScott the pregnancy lasted a matter of days and the boys can age themselves up. Of course there’s enough time for those things to happen, no ones questioning that, it’s the speed of the things that happens that is highly unusual so you can’t really use that for a measure of time.

Answer (score 10):

Monica first goes to Westview around three weeks after Smart Hulk’s snap and Blip brought everyone back.

> **Hayward:** Come on, let's catch you up. It's been three weeks and you're the first to report. Can't say I'm surprised, Captain.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 4, “We Interupt This Program...”</sub>

Obviously Hayward's comment below on Wanda stealing Vision's body ends up being a lie but the time is probably correct to correlate with when Wanda went to see Vision’s body. As such we know that, that was nine days ago or roughly 2 to 3 weeks after the Blip. Presumably as shown in “Previously On” Wanda then travels straight to Westview and creates the Hex.

> **Hayward** Nine days ago. Maximoff stormed our facility, stole the Vision's body, and resurrected him.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 5, “On a Very Special Episode...”</sub>

I’m not sure there’s much of a clue of how long passed since the hex though but we’re talking a few weeks at max. Remember time passing inside isn’t exactly normal: Wanda’s pregnancy is only a couple of days at most and the boys can age themselves up. Then we don’t see too much time passing outside, some things that take a few days so we know a few weeks pass but nothing on the order or months or even years passing. There is the post credits scene but that takes place an indeterminate amount of time later.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MCU wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Blip), the blip occured on october 2023 (I'll continue to search for concordant sources).

The *begining of the end* of the show seems to be halloween night, From that moment, we can establish timeline through Vison action. And the all final then seems to occurs on november the first.

Considering the information from TheLethalCarrot post that the hex happend rouglhy one week after the blip, we can conclude the hex was up for 1 to 3 weeks.

Of course, I assume that halloween night occured on real halloween night.. I might be wrong about it.

Comment: I'd be highly surprised if any of the events we saw corresponded to actual events outside of the hex.

Comment: Now I want to watch the show again for signs of automn and winter outside the hex.

Comment: The same wiki I used as source for the blip time place Wanda attack on SWORD on hallowen day... and put the battle on westview on 11th november. Can I edit my answer with info from the wiki, or as it is a wiki, it is not a safe enough source ?

Comment: The Blip time is because of the 5 year gap in Endgame. The MCU wiki is generally correct but does seem to make a lot of assumptions on dates. Does it cite evidence for it being Halloween? Also remember it was never an attack :)

Comment: I am not sure that the Halloween episode is supposed to be happening during the real Halloween (out of the Hex). It probably happened because Wanda wanted it, like there could have been a Christmas or a Thanksgiving episode I am like Wanda, I grow watching US TV shows and Halloween episodes were memorable because they are about something that is totally foreign to my country. Also, before the Internet era, it took time to have TV shows broadcasted out of the USA, so Halloween episodes were seldom seen by non-Americans on Halloween.